# How to delete a specific data in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code and it doesn't work it says that `dbRef.remove()` is not a function.

```
DeleteData1.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{

   var deleteCrop1 = document.getElementById('deleteCrop').value;

   const dbRef = ref (database, 'Crops/'+deleteCrop1);

if(document.getElementById('deleteCrop').value == ''){
   alert("Fields cannot be empty");
}else{
   dbRef.remove();
   alert("Data removed successfully")''
}


});
```

I tried using the docs in firebase but my code just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

With the v9 SDK, there is no longer a `remove()` method on a DatabaseReference object.   Instead, you should use the [`remove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#remove) function and pass the reference to it.

```
remove(dbRef)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the information. I tried it, it says that it was successfully deleted, but upon checking it's not deleted on the database. 

      remove(ref(database, "Crops/"+deleteCrop1.onValue))
      .then(()=>{
         alert("Crop successfully deleted");
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
         alert("Unsuccessful, error" + error);
      })

Comment: That's a different problem than the one you originally posted.  Please post a new question explaining in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  Your question should contain enough information that anyone can use the reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok thanks, Ill create a new question. Thanks Doug.